# Matrix Transformation to Reduce bitmap or Zoom In

Tags: c#, system.drawing, drawing2d

Let's say I have a bitmap 500px and I'm drawing a line at run time on it. When the line max point is 250px, it normally stops right in the middle of the bitmap (since the width of the bitmap is double the size of the line).

Is there a way to tell the bitmap or the Graphics.Drawline or using Matrix (not sure) to have the line go all the way til the end, like if I were zooming in?

I'm reading about Matrix Transformation, is that the right way to achieve that?

Comment: Matrix transformation (IIRC from graphic module from Uni) would involve a 2d array with various co-efficients against certain axis.  I think this might be a bit heavyweight, cant you just double the length of the line?

Comment: By double the length you mean to double the X values on the array I'm passing to the GraphicsPath?? The problem is that I don't know what's the real max length of the line/curve until I add that to my array. Not sure if you mean to recalculate the values inside the array after I fill it with the right values

Comment: Use Graphics.ScaleTransform().

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Hans Passant !!
The solution is to use the method

```
myGraphicsInstance.ScaleTransform(float , float);
```

available on the Graphics Class